# NullReferenceException occuring in System.Windows.Forms.Timer tick event

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple class with two variables and a Close function which is called from OnTimerTick. On very rare occasions a NullReferenceException is occurring in Close() function, but I fail to understand what those occasions can be. Can somebody explain?

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();
//timer.Tick is wired up in Constructor to OnTimerTick

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Tick -= OnTimerTick;
    Close();
}

private void Close()
{
    if (varOne != null)
    {
        varOne.SomeEvent -= onSomeEvent;
        varOne.Dispose();
        varOne = null;
    }

    if (varTwo != null)
    {
        varTwo.AnotherEvent -= onAnotherEvent;
        varTwo.Dispose();
        varTwo = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably depends alot on what varOne and varTwo are.

Comment: Can't you see in the debugger on which line the exception happens?

Comment: @monkey_p 
I've never encountered it during a debug session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no other threads are mutating your variables, and assuming that `onSomeEvent` and `onAnotherEvent` are on the current instance (i.e. no chance of a null reference there), then perhaps the most likely thing is that `Dispose()` is throwing?

This is possible - typically when in an error-state (indeed, it plagues WCF); try wrapping the dispose.

Oh; I'm also assuming here that `varTwo` has simple event handlers; it is also **entirely possible** for an event unsubscribe to fail; for example, if it is using an `EventHandlerList` and has already thrown it away...

So putting those together, something like:

```
// very paranoid cleanup
try {varOne.SomeEvent -= onSomeEvent; }
catch (Exception ex) { Trace.WriteLine(ex); } // best endeavours...
try { varOne.Dispose(); }
catch (Exception ex) { Trace.WriteLine(ex); } // best endeavours...
```

Normally this type of paranoia isn't necessary; but sometimes it is.

Comment: Well, the stack trace shows that the Close function throws. If it was Dispose or event unsubscribe that threw then shouldn't that reflect in the stack trace.

Comment: Stack traces can lie. Especially in release with optimisations such as (JIT) inlining.

Comment: Well, the stack trace did lie in my case.